# To use (DataContext) or not to use

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I've got a dilemma regarding the DataContext. Let's inspect the following piece of XAML:

```
<Window xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Controls"
        ... >
    ...
    <my:MyControl Name="{Binding Prop1}" Value="{Binding Prop2}" />
</Window>
```

Obviously, the Window's code-behind contains something like:

```
DataContext = someViewModel;
```

Author's intentions are clear - he wants to bind `MyControl`'s `Name` and `Value` to `Window`'s `DataContext`'s `Prop1` and `Prop2`. And this will of course work. Unless. (dramatic pause)

Unless `MyControl` is a composite `UserControl`, which also wants to take advantage of short notation of bindings and sets its `DataContext` to its own viewmodel. Because then it will become clear, that the bindings in `Window's` XAML actually bind to `MyControl`'s `DataContext` (previously inherited from `Window`'s one) and now they will stop working (or worse, will keep working if `MyControl`'s viewmodel actually contains properties named `Prop1` and `Prop2`<sup>1</sup>).

In this particular case solution is to bind in `Window`'s code explicitly:

```
<Window x:Name="rootControl"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Controls"
        ... >
    ...
    <my:MyControl Name="{Binding ElementName=rootControl, Path=DataContext.Prop1}" 
                  Value="{Binding ElementName=rootControl, Path=DataContext.Prop2}" />
</Window>
```

**TL;DR** If we're using short notation of bindings (when binding to `DataContext`) we may encounter quite tough to nail bugs resulting from bindings suddenly pointing to wrong `DataContext`.

My question is: how to use short binding notation without risk, that I'll bind to wrong `DataContext`? Of course I may use the short notation *when I'm sure*, that I'll be using inherited `DataContext` and long notation *when I'm sure*, that control will modify its `DataContext`. But that "*I'm sure*" will work only until first mistake, which will consume another hour of debugging.

Maybe I'm not following some MVVM rule? E.g. for example `DataContext` should be set only once on the top level and all composited controls should bind to something else?

---

<sup>1</sup> I've gone through that, actually. The `Window`'s `DataContext` contained a property named (say) `Prop` and the control replaced its `DataContext` with a class, which also contained a property `Prop` and everything worked fine. Problem appeared when I tried to use (unconsciously) the same pattern with non-matching property names.

---

By request:

Fragment of MyControl's code:

```
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Name.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public int Value
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

Window's viewmodel:

```
public class WindowViewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // (...)

    public string Prop1
    {
        get
        {
            return prop1;
        }
        set
        {
            prop1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Prop1");
        }
    }

    public int Prop2
    {
        get
        {
            return prop2;
        }
        set
        {
            prop2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Prop2");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Now assume, that on changing of `Name` and `Value` dependency properties, `MyControl` generates some viewmodel and executes the code:

```
model = new MyControlViewModel(Name, Value);
this.DataContext = model;
```

And internal `MyControl` controls bind to this DataContext.

From now on, the original `Name` and `Value` bindings will no longer work.

Comment: did you ever hear of dependency properties? simply create those in your usercontrol and bind to it. btw why your MyControl has its "own" viewmodel?

Comment: @blindmeis Of course I've heared. Data is passed to that user control by dependency properties (as you can see in the example). But that user control is a composite control, which processes the passed data and generates some more data to its embedded controls, and that's why I'm creating "own" viewmodel of that composite control. Of course I may pass all required data to that user control, but I'd then have to copy the same code to all places, where this control is being used.

Comment: i dont see dependency properties in your code. can you post some more code (the xaml for your myUsercontrol and the viewmodel code)? i cant see the problem atm.

Comment: i don't get it, usercontrols are basically just datatemplates...

Comment: @StefanDenchev As far as I know, usercontrols are regular (potentially composite) controls, not datatemplates...

Comment: can you pls post the xaml binding for Name and Value in your MyUserControl too. till now everything looks good :)

Comment: UserControls aren't meant to be full-blown controls afaik... [Read that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problems by simply *not* using what you call a 'composite control. While I understand that you want to encapsulate some functionality in the associated view model, you don't need to set the view model to the `UserControl.DataContext` internally.

What I mean by this is that you *can* have a view model for any or all of your `UserControl`s, but they're *data classes*, not *UI classes*, so keep them out of the view code. If you use this method of adding `DataTemplate`s into `Resources`, then you won't need to set any `DataContext` properties at all:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:YourUserControlViewModel}">
    <Views:YourUserControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

The final difference is that you should add your view model for your `UserControl`s as properties in a parent view model. This way, you still have no duplicated code (except maybe just a property declaration) and more importantly, you have no `Binding` problems from mixing `DataContext` values.

---

UPDATE >>>

When using this `DataTemplate` method of hooking up views and view models, you can display your view by `Binding` your view model property to the `Content` property of a `ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding YourViewModelProperty}" />
```

At run time, this `ContentControl` will be rendered as whatever view or `UserControl` that you defined in the `DataTemplate` of the relevant type for that property. Note that you shouldn't set the `x:Key` of the `DataTemplate`, otherwise you'd also need to set the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` property and that can limit the possibilities afforded by this method.

For example, *without* setting the `x:Key` property on your `DataTemplate`s, you could have a property of a base type and by setting it to different sub class, you can have different views for each from the one `ContentControl`. That is the basis of all of my views... I have one property of a base class view model data bound like this example and to change views, I just change the property to a new view model that is derived from the base class.

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

Here's the thing... you shouldn't have any 'proxy' object in your `UserControl`s doing anything... it should *all* be done through properties. So just declare a `DependencyProperty` of the type of that object and supply it from the view model through data `Binding`. Doing it this way means that it will be easy to test the functionality of that class, whereas testing code behind views is not.

And finally, yes, it's perfectly fine doing this in MVVM:

```
<Controls:SomeUserControl DataContext="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}" />
```

The overriding goal of MVVM is just to provide separation between the UI code and the view model code, so that we can easily test what's in the view models. That is why we try to remove as much functionality code from the views as possible.

Comment: It seem to go in the correct direction, but imagine this situation: I have a a few big models which has common part (say, `Model.CommonPart`) . The control I'm talking about is an editor for that part. How can I use the pattern presented by you to embed that editor in the main view? How to bind that common part of the main model to it?

Comment: Thanks for the update. That starts to make sense; but my scenario is yet a little bit more complicated: I'm passing the submodel to the control, but inside the control a proxy object for that model is being created and the whole interaction is done with that proxy object. Currently that proxy object is in my internal datacontext - where should I put this object instead? Or maybe I should do it in another way?

Comment: Be careful - the binding inside binds to the `DataContext` you are just changing :) This is how I've run into trouble. I guess, that there should be `{Binding ElementName=rootControl, Path=DataContext.SomeViewModelProperty}` instead. Am I right?

Comment: That depends on how you set up your `Binding`s inside the `UserControl`. I tend to use `RelativeSource FindAncestor Bindings` so that they find the right values each time regardless of the setting of the `DataContext`. That is pretty much the same as your `ElementName` way, but although more verbose, I prefer the `RelativeSource` way.

Answer (score 3):

> Unless MyControl is a composite UserControl, which also wants to take advantage of short notation of bindings and sets its DataContext to its own viewmodel.

And that's where I stopped reading.  This is, imho, a MVVM ***anti-pattern***.

The reason for this is twofold.  First, you screw with anybody who is using the control.  "Hey," you say, "you can't bind your stinky VM to my beautiful UI.  You have to use MY custom VM!"  But what if your VM is hard to use, lacks logic or features needed by the overall application?  What happens when, to use your UI, we have to translate our VM/models back and forth with your VM?  Pain in the butt.

Second is that your custom control is UI.  Its logic is UI logic, and so it is unnecessary to use a view model.  It is better to expose DependencyProperties on your control and update your UI as necessary.  That way anybody can bind to your UI and use it with any model or view model.

Comment: This control is an editor for a small sub-model which appears in many places, so it's quite handy for me to use it instead of doubling/tripling/quadrupling/... its logic. On the other hand it does have some internal logic and I thought, that introducing a viewmodel and model inside matches the MVVM idea. For example, data for list inside this control is provided from the control's viewmodel held in its datacontext. I mostly agree with you, but how else would you design such control?

Comment: @Spook: Depends... Probably I'd expect the DataContext to be the object I'd be editing, and use a DataTemplate to ensure the two meet when needed.  Logic in the codebehind.  Controls bind directly to the sub-model, or not, depending on whether the control has a submit button or undo-redo functionality...

Comment: Yes, but that includes you need to bother with view models of custom controls wherever you are using them, it complicates the design of your view models and usage. It enables a little bit more flexibility but to the expense of practicality. When I am making my own controls I make them be as easy to use as possible, that is my number 1 goal. That means less typing and less code duplication.

Comment: I like having my control as a separate unit and just give it mandatory parameters in order to be able to function. Things that you use most often should get the most attention.

Comment: "we have to translate our VM/models back and forth with your VM" you don't, you just replace DataContext with your VM. It's just that VM is in control itself, it does not mean it can't be replaced, but it means you do not need to carry around that VM (property) in all parent VMs that use this control.

Answer (score 1):

I've never met such a problem. It seems to be a little bit theoretical to me but maybe because of my approach to working with DataContext in WPF.

1. I minimize the explicit use `DataContext` property. I set it manually only for windows.
2. I have one dedicated method which is responsible for displaying new windows and it is the only one place where the `DataContext` property is set explicitly.
3. `DataContext` property for Windows is set to root ViewModel which contains child ViewModels, which contain...
4. I allow WPF to select which View should be used to display given a ViewModel by using `DataTemplate`
5. In my application I have a single `ResourceDictionary` which contains mappings between all ViewModels and Views.

Answer (score 1):

within a usercontrol you should never set the datacontext to "this" or a new viewmodel. a developer/user of your MyUsercontrol expect that the datacontext inherit from top to bottom (from mainwindow to your myusercontrol).

your usercontrol  xaml should use element binding

MyUserControl.xaml

```
 <UserControl x:Name="uc">
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Name}"/>
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=Value}"/>
```

this means your following code will work now in every situation

```
<Window xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Controls"> 
  <my:MyControl Name="{Binding Prop1}" Value="{Binding Prop2}" />
</Window>
```

the property Prop1 from Datacontext mainwindow is bound to the DP Name from your MyUsercontrol and the Textblock.Text within your MyUsercontrol is bound to the DP Name.

Comment: Ok, but what about data, which is used only internally and generated basing on Name and Value values? Should I also publish it through a DP and bind to from internal controls? (eg. `{Binding ElementName=rootControl, Path=SomeGeneratedData}`)